# Dynamically order divs around square and rotate them after square side ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Similar to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708135/js-hard-to-position-divs-around-a-circle).

Now I am facing this problem shown in the jsfiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkqBD/2/

The square div in the middle represents a restaurant table surrounded by guest on the table. Divs are now ordered as on circle table but I need to position them facing the square / table. The problem is that the number of guest on table is dynamically changed.. How I can position them so each guest chair image to be faced to table?
This is my code so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('.circleBase').each(function(){
    var d = $(this).attr("id");
    var tbltype = $(this).attr("tbltype");
    if(tbltype==="1"){
      border = "1";
    }else { border = "999";}
      var elems='';
      var x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;
      var rot = 0;
      if(tbltype==="1"){
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('info_container22 square');
        var totContent = $(this).find(elems).size();
        var increase = Math.PI * 2 / totContent;
        for (var i = 0; i < totContent; i++) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        x = (120 * Math.cos(angle) + 40);
        y = (115 * Math.sin(angle) + 60);
        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
        elem.style.left = x + 'px';
        elem.style.top = y + 'px';
        var rot = 88 + (i * (360 / totContent));
        var img = $(elems[i]).find('.img');
        img.css('-moz-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css.MozTransform = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
        img.css('-webkit-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('-o-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('-ms-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('zIndex', "10");
        angle += increase;
      }
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: common guys, give same ideas at least..

Comment: How should it look like if the number of chairs is odd?

Comment: I suppose ugly :) that's why I searched for universal solution

Comment: You should know how the result would look like. Is there on more chair on one side or is it on the corner or in the middle of the table?

Comment: well, it is better if possible to be fitted in any side of the table, otherwise corners are the only available space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is it will be easier with a square table but you need a different algorithm for that:

lines: 
x = (120 * Math.cos(angle) + 40);
y = (115 * Math.sin(angle) + 60);
.... and
var rot = 88 + (i * (360 / totContent));

should be changed. plus you shouldn't have angle += increase; since it will be calculated in  another way

In more detail:

You have a square table so you will have 4 distinct rotation angle 0,90,180,270 left,bottom,right,top side sespectively
Secondly let "side_num" be a variable how many people sit on one side

As we loop through 'guests' array 'j' is increased by 1 as 'i' is until it reaches 'side_num' if so 'j' becomes 0 and angle as well as x, y-s are changed as well.

Now calculate which side a person will sit by: (j mod 'side_num') ( since we have 4 side of the table)

x and y's should have calculated based on (j mod 'side_num') too so left side will have the same x values etc.

I will correct the code but this is the theory behind it

http://jsfiddle.net/Krisztian123/hyGrj/32/
Almost done:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$('.circleBase').each(function(){
var d = $(this).attr("id");
var tbltype = $(this).attr("tbltype");
if(tbltype==="1"){
border = "1";
}else { border = "999";}
       var elems='';
         var x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;
        var rot = 0;
       if(tbltype==="1"){
      var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('info_container22 square');
        //alert(elems.length);
        var side_num = 4; //how many seats per side
     //   side_num -= 1; //technically it should be 3 
        var j = 0;
        var angles=['270','180','270','90'];

        var xs=[0,38,0,0];
        var ys=[38,0,0,0];

        var x_fix=[-50,0,0,0]
        var y_fix=[-30,130,0,0]
        var cur_side = 0; //(0,1,2,3 == left, bottom,right,top)
        var totContent = $(this).find(elems).size();
        var j = -1; //to be equal to loop index
        for (var i = 0; i < totContent; i++) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        j++; // like (0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2...)
            if (j == side_num) {
                //next side
                j = 0;
                cur_side++;
                if (cur_side == 4) {
                    alert("places are full next table");
                }
            }
        x = x_fix[cur_side] + j*xs[cur_side];
        y = y_fix[cur_side] + j*ys[cur_side];

        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
        elem.style.left = x + 'px';
        elem.style.top = y + 'px';
        var rot = angles[cur_side];
        var img = $(elems[i]).find('.img');
        img.css('-moz-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css.MozTransform = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
        img.css('-webkit-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('-o-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('-ms-transform', "rotate("+rot+"deg)");
        img.css('zIndex', "10");

  }
            }
                              });

          });
```

Comment: will add another 8 seats, but it is a piece of cake from now on. 
will comment the lines to be clear
I use array to have the increments and fix values but don't be afraid.. if you calculate those so called fix values in x_fix and y_fix array from the coordinates of the square table and the increments from the size of the image of the seat you use you will end up having a general function that can be used with any kind of square or rectengular shaped table

Comment: updated jsfiddle again, have a look; hope you get the idea how to elaborate this into making the code independent of table size too. Also the only thing it does one you have more people 'trying to sit' is an alert box appearing, That is also should have some more suitable solution

Comment: Chris, which is the updated version of jsfiddle because this http://jsfiddle.net/Krisztian123/hyGrj/32/ it isn't ?

Comment: And Chris, I the  jsfiddle.net/Krisztian123/hyGrj/32 I added 11 guests/chairs and it doesn't work. It is rotating only left and bottom chairs and the rest are not located in right and top, but in the center(table).. What is the correct jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell you which link is the new one

Comment: Chris, Good job man ! Thank you very much for your help !I accepted as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

1. Reserve an extra chair if number of chairs is uneven ( number_of_chairs % number_of_table_sides)
2. Divide the rest of the chairs by the number of table sides
3. For each table side the number of chairs is the result of 2.
4. Divide the border length of the current table side of by the number of chairs
5. Place the chairs with an offset according to the border lenght.
6. The rotation of the chair is 360/number_of_table sides * current_side
7. If there is an extra chair because the number of chairs is odd place it somewhere. Perhaps add it to the last side of the table making the chairs on that side a little closer together.

Hope that helps. Are you writing a poker game?

Comment: Max, your solution sounds harder than Chris's one.. the problem is that I can not complete none of them :) and No, I have nothing to do with Poker games :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a fairly straightforward way using flexbox. It'd even be responsive and the chairs would recalculate their position on browser or container resize. The only downside of course is that browser support isn't yet 100%. But I thought I'd just post this idea anyway as it may be useful in the future.

In the HTML you'd just write a normal list of names:

```
<ul class="names">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Jordan</li>
    <li>Vania</li>
    <li>Martin</li>
    <li>Tony</li>
    <li>Ivan</li>
    <li>Maria</li>
    <li>Edward</li>
    <li>Edward</li>
</ul>
```

Then javascript would create this markup somewhere (it could be placed anywhere):

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="l"></div>
</div>
```

*Note: All elements here have their CSS property of `box-sizing` set to `border-box`.*

The `.table-container` div is just a container for the `.table` and other elements. It has no set width (so it's responsive) but it does have a fixed height. This height is determined in javascript and is based upon the chairs dimensions. For example, if you say that a chair is 40px high and that you want the table to be 3 high then the `.table-container` div will be 40px * 5 in height (40px * 3) + (40px * 2 (for padding for the chairs around the table)).

The `.table` div is just a regular div with the only CSS property of `height: 100%;` set. This is because `.table-container` already has the correct paddings so the `.table`'s content area is also already the correct size.

The `.t`, `.r`, `.b` and `.l` divs standing for top, right, bottom and left are absolutely positioned divs relative to the `.table-container` div. These are effectively what hold the rows of chairs. Each of these divs has their `justify-content` and `align-content` CSS properties set to `space-around`. This means whenever you add a new element to them they are automatically and correctly spaced so it'll look nice. No need for any algorithm.

So now all that's left to do is to create those elements in javascript, fetch the list of names and then append each name to the correct div (either top, right, bottom or left). I just cycled through the names one by one appending them in a clockwise motion.

Rough example: http://jsbin.com/oFIXOZUf/2/edit.

Comment: Dear Matt, this is a nice solution but what you said about the browser support is kind of embarrassing. What is the browser support on average? If you are talking about not supporting IE 6 even 7 but all mozillas and opera that's ok.. And something esle - your script doesn't rotate chairs faced towards to table - can this be done? Thank you for helping me as well !

Comment: @thecore7 Yes rotating the image and manipulating any aspect of each side is easy. But as for flexbox support, [it isn't great](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and is a little complicated right now.

Comment: Matt, I checked the browser support and even being nice solution, chances to be used by many people is low.. Realy nice try but as I said if nobody applaud (mean visitors who use it) what is the sense of time spent for making it.. Thank you for your help ! I appreciate it !